# C# Unhadled.Exception: System.NullReferenceException Visual Studio

Tags: c#, symbols, unhandled-exception

I have a problem with Console.WriteLine()

When I try to print mathematical signs (`+ , *`) and other symbols (`@, #,  \, ~ , ;, ", '`),
I receive Unhadled.Exception: System.NullReferenceException.

If I insert a letter from the alphabet or a number everything is alright.

```
string expression = Console.ReadLine();

        foreach (char symbol in expression)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(symbol);
        }
```

**Screenshot of NullReferenceException** 
[image: image 2]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/buDRZ.png

**Proof Image** 
[image: image 3]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAL7y.jpg

Comment: it means that your symbol variable does not contain anything

Comment: So what's line 15 of Program.cs?

Comment: The code you've provided doesn't display the behavior you describe.

Comment: Line 15 is: foreach (char symbol in expression)  This is the whole code. Nothing else.

Comment: use this:char [] input=console.readline().tochararray();then print array

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/1BrKPf <- no error.

Comment: But I want it my way. It should be working. Why do I receive exception?

Comment: Well that's certainly interesting. No idea what's going on. Voted to reopen.

Comment: Could it be the system locale? Mine is Japan.

Comment: I can't think of any reason that would make a difference, but maybe? Can you set a breakpoint and check whether `expression` is null after `ReadLine`?

Comment: I tried setting `CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture` to ja-JP and still don't see the behavior that's being described from the debugger.

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx) `Console.ReadLine()` can return `null` if Ctrl+Z (EOF) is pressed

Comment: I tried too. It's not the locale. I checked and <expression>  is never <null>. If I insert ++++ for example, it's value never changes. The funny thing is this happens only with Ctrl+F5. If  I try with F5 everything is alright.

Comment: I solved my problem. I restored a previous System Backup. Everything is back to normal.